# How to make editText focusable on button click in Android?

Tags: android

on onCreate method i am making all editText disable by using setFocusable method.
But on button click i want to set focus again. I have implemented this , but now working.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.contactform);

            name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
            phone_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number);

           name.setFocusable(false);
           address.setFocusable(false);
           phone_number.setFocusable(false);
           email.setFocusable(false);

    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.editButton:
                  Toast.makeText(this, "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    name.setFocusable(true);
                    name.setFocusable(true);
                    address.setFocusable(true);
                    phone_number.setFocusable(true);
                    email.setFocusable(true);

                break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
```

Comment: Simply use setFocusable(true) instead setEnabled(true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :

```
setFocusable(true)
setFocusableInTouchMode(true)
```

Instead :

```
setEnabled(true)
```

Comment: @user3288891,Now you use setFocusable(true) in ur code before you used  setEnable(true).